# Fail to use IHostingEnvironment to get path

Tags: startup, filepath, asp.net-core-webapi, environment, server.mappath

I'm creating project api in .Net Core 2.1, in my startup.cs, I added:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPathProvider, PathProvider>();
```

After that, reate IPathProvider interface and class:

```
public interface IPathProvider
{
    string MapPath(string path);
}

public class PathProvider : IPathProvider
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public PathProvider(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    public string MapPath(string path)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, path);
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

And then, in my api cs file, I write code:

```
private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public PowerControlController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }
public string MapPath(string path)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, path);
        return filePath;
    }
```

Now, in main api, I call mappath:

```
public ActionResult<string> GetListPowerSwitch()
    {
        try
        {
            var path = MapPath("../DataDen/DataDen.xml");
            return path;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

It's work well when debug in local. But, when I publish it to IIS Web Server as new application, it's return ex.ToString() that:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1
>      at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
>      at LedControlPowerApi.Controllers.PowerControlController.GetListPowerSwitch() in E:\PROJECT EMEC\LedControlPrj\LedControlPowerApi\Controllers\PowerControlController.cs:line 55

Line 55 is: `var path = MapPath("../DataDen/DataDen.xml");`
Anyone tell me how to fix this bug ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `ContentRoot` instead of `WebRoot` because for ASP.NET Core 2 API project there is no `wwwroot` folder in published API project.

Check this https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6688

Comment: Thanks, but it's still fail. But have a solution from your link, I added this code `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env.WebRootPath)) env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");` to startup Configure and api is work well.

Comment: Yep. Using `ContentRootPath` instead of `WebRootPath` worked.